# How can I create a views.py that allows a registered user to create, amend and delete a appointment?

Tags: python, django

I am developing a barber booking service using Django/Python. I want to create a view for an authenticated user to create a booking, amend and/or delete their booking. I am a student developer and this particular issue is not covered in the lessons and I am a little overwhelmed by it all, I have done many searches online but have not had any luck with finding anything I am able to work with.

So far I have managed to create the models.py code but have hit a brick wall when it comes to creating the views.py, any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

My current models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


SERVICE_CHOICES = (

    ("Classic Cut", "Classic cut"),
    ("Cut & Beard", "Cut & Beard"),
    ("Skin Fade", "Skin Fade"),
    ("Skin & Beard", "Skin & Beard"),
    ("Buzz Cut", "Buzz Cut"),
)

TIME_CHOICES = (

    ("9 AM", "9 AM"),
    ("10 AM", "10 AM"),
    ("11 AM", "11 AM"),
    ("1 PM", "1 PM"),
    ("2 PM", "2 PM"),
    ("3 PM", "3 PM"),
    ("4 PM", "4 PM"),
    ("5 PM", "5 PM"),
)


class Appointment(models.Model):
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    service = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, choices=SERVICE_CHOICES, default="Classic Cut")
    day = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    time = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=TIME_CHOICES, default="9 AM")
    time_ordered = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} | day: {self.day} | time: {self.time}"

I have managed to update my code a little to create an appointment, my views.py code so far is 

class AppointmentCreate(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        appointment = None
        return render(request, "appointments.html", {"appointment": appointment})

    # Get service, day and time submitted via POST request and ensure that
    # service and day fields are completed
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        service = request.POST.get('service')
        day = request.POST.get('day')
        time = request.POST.get('time')
        if service == '' or day == '':
            messages.error(request, "Please Select A Service and Date")
        #Storing day and service in django session
        request.session['service'] = service
        request.session['day'] = day
        request.session['time'] = time

        appointment = Appointment(service=service, day=day)
        appointment.save()

I anyone is able to advise/help with the user being able to view their appointment and edit/delete. Many thanks!
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are facing? 
You need to create a `url`, `form`, `html template` and `view` to complete the functionality. Which part are you facing an issue with?

Answer (score 0):

to create the views for an authenticated user to create, amend and delete their booking you need to define corresponding view functions in your `views.py`

so your `views.py` should looks something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import Appointment
from .forms import AppointmentForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def create_appointment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AppointmentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            appointment = form.save(commit=False)
            appointment.user = request.user
            appointment.save()
            return redirect('appointment_detail', pk=appointment.pk)
    else:
        form = AppointmentForm()
    return render(request, 'appointment_edit.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def edit_appointment(request, pk):
    appointment = get_object_or_404(Appointment, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AppointmentForm(request.POST, instance=appointment)
        if form.is_valid():
            appointment = form.save(commit=False)
            appointment.user = request.user
            appointment.save()
            return redirect('appointment_detail', pk=appointment.pk)
    else:
        form = AppointmentForm(instance=appointment)
    return render(request, 'appointment_edit.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def delete_appointment(request, pk):
    appointment = get_object_or_404(Appointment, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        appointment.delete()
        return redirect('appointment_list')
    return render(request, 'appointment_confirm_delete.html', {'appointment': appointment})
```

you will also need to create a corresponding `forms.py` file to define the form for creating and editing appointments like this:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Appointment


class AppointmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ['service', 'day', 'time']
```

you need to create HTML templates for create, edit and delete views

for create and edit `appointment_edit.html`:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
</form>
```

for deleting `appointment_confirm_delete.html`:

```
<p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ appointment }}"?</p>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

and your `urls.py` should be like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('appointment/create/', views.create_appointment, name='create_appointment'),
    path('appointment/<int:pk>/edit/', views.edit_appointment, name='edit_appointment'),
    path('appointment/<int:pk>/delete/', views.delete_appointment, name='delete_appointment'),
]
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: This is extremely helpful thank you so much! I've made some changes to my appointmentcreate class last night which I've updated on my post for you to see, out of curiosity as you've put @login_required, on my site the appointment link on the homepage only shows if the user has already registered to the site, would that make a difference in your examples?